# Как убрать слово "Личное" рядом с заголовком личной записи wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

[image: фото]
Не могу найти где прописано чтобы вставлялся этот текст в теме https://ru.wordpress.org/themes/atomic-blocks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не зависит от темы, это функционал WordPress. Попробуйте сделать вот так:

```
function title_format($content) {
    return '%s';
}
add_filter('private_title_format', 'title_format');
add_filter('protected_title_format', 'title_format');
```